# Google cloud vision api detects different number of labels

Tags: python, google-cloud-vision

As per [this page](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/stable/vision/index.html), the following code snippet returns 5 labels:

```
from google.cloud import vision
url = 'https://farm9.staticflickr.com/8215/8267748261_ea142faf5e.jpg'

client = vision.ImageAnnotatorClient()
client.label_detection({'source': {'image_uri': url}}) # yields 5
```

When I do it as described [here](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/detecting-labels#vision-label-detection-python), I get 10 labels:

```
client = vision.Client()
image = client.image(source_uri=url)
labels = image.detect_labels() # yields 10
```

When I use the [Cloud Vision demo page](https://cloud.google.com/vision/), I get 18 labels for the same image.

Why do these approaches all differ? What am I missing here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**TL;DR** - `image.detect_labels` takes an optional `limit` parameter which has a default value of `10` and hence you get only `10` labels in your second version. If you increase the limit to a value higher than `18`, you will get the same result as the one you observed on the Cloud Vision demo page.

#### Doc for `detect_labels()`

> Help on method `detect_labels` in module `google.cloud.vision.image`:
>
> `detect_labels(self, limit=10)` method of
>   `google.cloud.vision.image.Image` instance
>
> ```
> Detect labels that describe objects in an image.
>
> :type limit: int
> :param limit: The maximum number of labels to try and detect.
>
> :rtype: list
> :returns: List of :class:`~google.cloud.vision.entity.EntityAnnotation`
> ```

#### Working example using `Image.detect_labels()`

Try this:

```
from google.cloud import vision

IMAGE_URL = 'https://farm9.staticflickr.com/8215/8267748261_ea142faf5e.jpg'

vision_client = vision.Client()

image = vision_client.image(source_uri=IMAGE_URL)
labels = image.detect_labels(limit=100)
print('Label Count: {0}'.format(len(labels))) # Result is 18
print('Labels:')
for label in labels:
    print(label.description)
```

#### Working example using `ImageAnnotatorClient.annotate_image()`

You can set the max number of results (which defaults to `5` here) when using `ImageAnnotatorClient` too, although the request gets slightly verbose:

```
from google.cloud import vision

IMAGE_URL = 'https://farm9.staticflickr.com/8215/8267748261_ea142faf5e.jpg'

annot_client = vision.ImageAnnotatorClient()
request_image = {'source': {'image_uri': IMAGE_URL}}
label_detection_feature = {
    'type': vision.enums.Feature.Type.LABEL_DETECTION, 'max_results': 100}
request_features = [label_detection_feature]
response = annot_client.annotate_image(
    {'image': request_image, 'features': request_features})
print('Label Count: {0}'.format(len(response.label_annotations))) # Result is 18
```

#### Example using `ImageAnnotatorClient.label_detection()`

If you use `ImageAnnotatorClient.label_detection()` directly, it always defaults to a maximum of `5` results and there does not seem to be a way to configure this limit.

```
from google.cloud import vision

IMAGE_URL = 'https://farm9.staticflickr.com/8215/8267748261_ea142faf5e.jpg'

annot_client = vision.ImageAnnotatorClient()
response = annot_client.label_detection(image={'source': {'image_uri': IMAGE_URL}})
print('Label Count: {0}'.format(len(response.label_annotations))) # Result is 5
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks! Mental note to myself: When using python, don't forget to check the internal documentation also.
As a side question: Is this also documented online somewhere? It sure is not easy to find.

Comment: @Toby - The `max_result` field in the request using `ImageAnnotatorClient.annotate_image()` is documented [here](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/stable/vision/gapic/types.html#google.cloud.vision_v1.types.Feature.max_results) . The [`limit` argument to `Image.detect_labels()` is documented in an older version of the documentation](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/0.24.0/vision-image.html#google.cloud.vision.image.Image.detect_labels) unfortunately.

Comment: Update for the third example: Since 0.31.0 (#4817),  ImageAnnotatorClient.label_detection() has a max_results argument, found via Pythons internal help(). Or online [here](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/vision/gapic/v1/api.html)

Comment: Any idea on how to do this in the PHP version? (I only get 10 results, but need more) I have something like:

... = ImageAnnotatorClient()->labelDetection($image);

Comment: @Toby Link broken